# Class 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry' not found

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

My first ever time using Doctrine and I've got an error. I left my project the night before and this error didn't exist, booted up the web server on a new machine and greeted with this.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
>   'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry' not found in
>   D:\website\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Configuration.php:156
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\website\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup.php(72):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Configuration->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(Array, true) #1
>   D:\website\src\setup.php(16):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(Array,
>   true) #2 D:\website\src\bootstrap.php(6):
>   include('C:\Users\admin\...') #3 D:\website\public\index.php(7):
>   require('C:\Users\admin\...') #4 {main} thrown in
>   D:\website\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Configuration.php on
>   line 156

I've tried `composer update` and `composer install`, neither have helped.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$paths = array(ROOT . "/src/Database/Modals");
$config = $container->get('App\Providers\Config');

$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => $config->get('database.driver'),
    'user'     => $config->get('database.user'),
    'password' => $config->get('database.password'),
    'dbname'   => $config->get('database.name'),
);

$entityConfig = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, true);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $entityConfig);
```

It seems to throw the exception for this line of code.

```
$entityConfig = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, true);
```

Comment: Could you also post your composer.json as well as the PHP version of BOTH systems?

Comment: Try `composer require doctrine/annotations` it's a requirement but maybe it's broken in your code base

Comment: Could you check and  add if necessary the vendor directory to the excludePaths option?
There have been reports where the `..`  presence in the configs can break it

Comment: maybe this? https://github.com/goaop/framework/issues/291

Answer (score 11):

The comment above by @martin-barker did the trick for me:

```
composer require doctrine/annotations
```

Answer (score 1):

1) connect you server using ssh.

2) Locate the path that your script work.

3) Run `composer require doctrine/annotations`

4) You can find vendor dir in FTP

5) Declare a require to vendor on your code. like `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'`

Let me know if helps.